# using a variable as host in hostvars

Tags: ansible

I am using hostvars this way:

```
{{ hostvars['host']['something'] }}
```

and It's working fine. However, I want to use a variable name for hostname so I have done the following:

```
{{ hostvars[item]['something'] }}
with_items: groups['myhost']
```

and it's working but with a warning message:

```
[DEPRECATION WARNING]: Using bare variables is deprecated. Update your playbooks so that the environment value uses the full 
variable syntax ('{{groups["myhost"]}}').
This feature will be removed in a future release. Deprecation warnings can be disabled 
by setting deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg.
```

is there a way I can achieve the same without the need to use deprecated stuff?

Answer (score 0):

[Duplicate]
The solution is:

```
{{ hostvars[item]['something'] }}
with_items: "{{ groups['myhost'] }}"
```